# Does the food spoil in caravans?

Tags: rimworld

From [A16](https://ludeon.com/blog/2016/12/rimworld-alpha-16-wanderlust-released/) there is option to send out a [caravan](http://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Caravan). But you have to provide the food for the people on-board.

[image]

When I fill up the caravan with simple food with high deterioration rate, it says that there is 28 days worth of food even though the food should be rotten in 5 days.

**Does the food in the caravan rots away?**

Do the other things like raw meat spoils?

Comment: FYI: Unconfirmed - it does not spoil.

Comment: You should write an answer to your question on select the answer below just so the question is marked as answered.

Comment: Well the question will be marked as answered when there is quality answer. Which is not yet posted.

Comment: Ok then. I will do some testing tonight and post an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Alpha 17, it does. The interface now also shows when the food you take with you will spoil.

Answer (score 4):

#### !! This changed in the release of Alpha 17. This is no longer true. !!

---

Food does not spoil or deteriorate in a caravan.

I have sent a caravan back and forth in a 3 day journey with meat. Before leaving, every stack of meat were set to spoil in 1 day because they are not refrigerated and had 46/50 hit points since they were left out on the open for a few hours.

After the journey, none of those stats changed, so it is safe to say that nothing will spoil.

However, this could be something that is added in a future update since it looks at like like a missing functionality, which would make sense since this game is still in alpha.

**Note:** Tested in Alpha 16

Comment: This was true in Alpha 16 version, but changed in the following version; it now spoils in caravans.

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't any problems when I sent the caravan with simple meals and pemmican lasting about 20 days. In fact they ate the simple meals first before the pemmican.

Comment: I didn't have problems too. But it would be nice to have some thorough tests.

Comment: I think they will always prefer simple meals over pemmican, but it might be different for Ascetic characters. As for spoiling, in Alpha 16 it didn't but it changed in the following version.